# JSON get resource filtered by 2 tables

Tags: javascript, java, json, visual-studio, frontend

I have two JSON tables, one called "photos" and another one, called "votes" (which its resources have an "photoId" attribute, which represent the photo associate with the vote itself). The question is, its possible to filter using the 2 tables and getting the photos sorted based in their votes?

I have been triyng to do it with auxiliar function, but nothing worked and its too complicated. Is there a more ""easy"" way of doing it? Really appreciatte the answers, thank you.

"photos" table:

```
"photos": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559628129-67cf63b72248?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
  "title": "Gallo al natural",
  "description": "Una foto simple de un gallo con el fondo medio desenfocado",
  "date": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
  "tags": [
    "naturaleza",
    "gallo",
    "animales"
  ],
  "userId": 1
},
{
  "url": "https://coobis.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Github-branch-pullrequest.png",
  "title": "Github Workflow",
  "description": "Flujo de trabajo tipico en GitHub",
  "tags": [
    "github",
    "productivity",
    "workflow"
  ],
  "date": "2020-05-15T14:10:26.290Z",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "url": "https://www.diariomotor.com/imagenes/picscache/750x/mclaren-675lt-000_750x.jpg",
  "title": "McLaren 675LT",
  "description": "Mantis Green 675LT Coupe en pista, Woking\n",
  "tags": [
    "mclaren",
    "supercar",
    "V8"
  ],
  "date": "2020-05-15T14:13:02.186Z",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 3
},
{
  "url": "https://e00-expansion.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/11/28/15749453700404.jpg",
  "title": "El barco de mi prima",
  "description": "El barco de mi prima atracando en el puerto del Gualdalquivir",
  "tags": [
    "barco",
    "yate",
    "luxury",
    "gualdalquivir"
  ],
  "date": "2020-05-18T19:38:53.279Z",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 4
},
{
  "url": "https://image.freepik.com/foto-gratis/hoguera-bosque-muchacha-calentando-detras_90153-695.jpg",
  "title": "Candelita en el bosque",
  "description": "Jojojo candelita en el boske el otro dia con mis ermano.",
  "tags": [
    "candela",
    "fuego",
    "ermanos"
  ],
  "date": "2020-05-19T09:38:25.899Z",
  "userId": "8",
  "id": 5
},
{
  "url": "https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C561BAQFx_ZmuFHgbIA/company-background_10000/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=mpxVmfzk1ZtxPO5FUmPzKxOLEPYBX7gmkl1xmqXl89w",
  "title": "Cachimbitas",
  "description": "Cachimbones jojojo este veranito me pillo una al pasoo",
  "tags": [
    "shisha",
    "summer",
    "smoking",
    "bengala"
  ],
  "date": "2020-05-24T22:38:40.669Z",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 7
},
{
  "url": "https://blog.fuertehoteles.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/conil-de-la-frontera.jpg",
  "title": "Fotografía de Conil",
  "description": "Fotografía de conil de la frontera, en Cádiz",
  "tags": [
    "conil",
    "andalucia",
    "summer",
    "relax"
  ],
  "date": "2020-05-26T13:56:46.570Z",
  "userId": "13",
  "id": 8
},
{
  "url": "https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/08/13/15657012716256.jpg",
  "title": "Dreambeach",
  "description": "Festival Dreambeach en Almería",
  "tags": [
    "summer",
    "festival",
    "music"
  ],
  "date": "2020-05-28T08:44:13.822Z",
  "userId": "8",
  "id": 9
}
```

]

My "votes" table:

```
"votes": [
{
  "photoId": "8",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 1
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "photoId": "4",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 4
},
{
  "photoId": "8",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 6
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 7
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 8
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 9
},
{
  "photoId": "5",
  "userId": "8",
  "id": 10
},
{
  "photoId": "9",
  "userId": "8",
  "id": 11
},
{
  "photoId": "4",
  "userId": "14",
  "id": 12
}
```

],

By the way, i am using Apache server, and a API REST JSON for data.

Comment: Which language do you want to use to solve this? I see `javascript` and `java` in the question's tags. You may want to edit the question, to clarify. And also remove the irrelevant language tag from the question.

Comment: It is generally helpful to show us what you have tried, and where you are getting stuck - so maybe you can also add in the relevant formatted code.